# Print a word document from Python 3 after setting some printer properties

Tags: python, printing, docx

I have a word document that I would like to print from inside Python. I also need to set some printer properties, like the tray, duplex printing etc.
So far I have only partly succeeded to print, by using `win32api.ShellExecute` but this will open Word to print and it will get the printer properties set in Word, which is not desirable.
If I use `win32print` module I am able to set the properties as I want but I haven't been able to send the document to the printer.

In sort, the part of the code that seems to work for setting my printer properties is as follows:

```
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32print

# pDevMode Constants
# DefaultSource
TRAY_1 = 260
TRAY_2 = 259
# Duplex
SINGLE_SIDE = 1
DUPLEX_OVER = 2
DUPLEX_UP = 3
# Color
COLOR = 2
MONOCHROME = 1

device_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(device_name)

properties = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2)
devmode = properties['pDevMode']

devmode.DefaultSource = TRAY_1
devmode.Fields |= win32con.DM_DEFAULT_SOURCE

win32print.DocumentProperties(None, handle, device_name, devmode, devmode, win32con.DM_IN_BUFFER | win32con.DM_OUT_BUFFER)

hdc = win32gui.CreateDC("", device_name, devmode)
win32print.StartDoc(hdc, ("Print Document", None, None, 0))
win32print.StartPage(hdc)

...

win32print.EndPage(hdc)
win32print.EndDoc(hdc)
```

The above will print an empty page (as expected) from the correct tray.

I am not sure how to send the document though.
I have been reading my file and trying to send to the printer with:

```
            with open(document_path, "rb") as file:
                data = file.read()
                win32print.WritePrinter(printer_handle, data)
```

but doesn't work.

I am also a bit confused with StartDoc/StartDocPrinter, StartPage/StartPagePrinter functions in win32print... Whatever I tried so far didn't seem to work.

Any help would be much appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it working in the end...

Apparently there is no need for `win32gui.CreateDC`

What I was missing to actually register the pDevMode changes to the printer was:

```
win32print.SetPrinter(printer_handle, 2, properties, 0)
```

right after the *DocumentProperties* line.
For this to work though I had to add the PRINTER_DEFAULTS argument to the printer handle command as follows:

```
PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {
    "DesiredAccess": win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS
}

printer_handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name, PRINTER_DEFAULTS)
```

Then with a *ShellExecute* command I was able to print with the set settings